# Short film about a kid who grows feathers, and then turns into a bird

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching this in an airplane back in 2016-2017. It was a short film about a girl/boy with their mom/dad (can't remember which). The kid starts growing feathers, and both the kid and parent are scared. The parent then goes to find a doctor to try and help the kid (the doctor is very scary), but then the parent changes their mind and takes their kid back home. The moral of the story is that the kid just wanted to be free, and the parent had to let them go. The kid then turns into a bird and flies away.

Answer (score 6):

Could be [**Ricky**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1189076/), still it is a full length movie.

[IMDB link](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1189076/)

> Ricky is a 2009 French fantasy film directed by François Ozon about a
> human baby who develops a set of functional wings, and how the parents
> cope with the child's abnormality.

[Full movie on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6re6C-tR26w)

Wings:
[image]
Visit to the doctor (mom decides to take kid back to home):
[image]
Kid flies away:
[image]